# Função .play() em jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

#### Cenário teste

Tenho uma página com os seguintes elementos:

```
<audio id="aud1" src="audio/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
<audio id="aud2" src="audio/2.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
<audio id="aud3" src="audio/3.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
```

E uma função:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "x.php",
    type : "post",
    dataType: "text",
    data : data,
    cache: false,
    success : function(response) {
        if (response == '1') {
            document.getElementById('aud1').play();
        } else if (response == '2') {
            document.getElementById('aud2').play();
        } else if (response == '3') {
            document.getElementById('aud3').play();
        } else if (response == 'E'){
            alert('Erro.')
        }
    },
    error : function() {
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

Conforme o retorno da requisição por *ajax*, a função irá dar play no áudio. Funcionando perfeitamente.

---

#### Problema

Quando uso `$('#aud1').play()`, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).play is not a function

---

#### Dúvida

- Existe uma forma de dar "play" no áudio via *jQuery*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente o seu seletor está preenchido incorretamente, o seletor `$('aud1')` pegaria elemento do DOM com a tag aud1, e não com o id. Caso queira pegar pelo id, use `$('#aud1')`.

Mesmo que preenchendo corretamente, não funcionaria, pois hoje o jQuery não dá suporte ao `.play()` a partir de seu elemento. Inclusive isso já foi aberto como um bug e fechado como um `CLOSED FEATURE (WONTFIX)` no [bug tracker oficial do jQuery](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10374).

Para funcionar, você pode simplesmente acessar o elemento do DOM a partir do elemento jQuery pelo seu indice:

```
$('#aud1')[0].play();
```

Comment: Sobre o seletor, foi falha na digitação da pergunta mesmo rs... Sobre sua solução, realmente funcionou +1... Mas gostaria de saber o por que de usar o `[0]`? Seria pelo motivo de quando executo `$('#aud1')`, ele cria um `array` (ou obj?) de dados do elemento? Ou algo do tipo!?

Comment: Um elemento jQuery pode carregar multiplos elementos do DOM, por exempo, quando eu chamo `$('div')`, terei em mão todas as divs da página, e caso eu faça `$('div').addClass('teste')`, estarei adicionando a classe teste em todas elas.

Comment: Então, mas se eu chamo `$('#aud1')` porque então preciso do `[0]`? O que teria no caso de `[1]` então!? Não entendi se ele "desmancha" os dados do elemento, ou o que faz...

Comment: Como eu disse, o elemento jQuery carrega múltiplos elementos do DOM. Se você acessa o índice 0 com `[0]` você está simplesmente acessando o primeiro elemento dessa lista, com `[1]`, o segundo, e assim vai. Se você quer modificar em todos, terá que iterar sobre eles.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, fazer isto:

```
$('#aud1')
```

não vai trazer um elemento que tenha o método `.play()`
(não encontrei este método na documentação do jQuery, não pode confundir o objeto do jQuery com o do DOM).

Se quer usar o `.play()`, que é nativo do HTML, precisa pegar o elemento do DOM.

Em jQuery se faz desta forma:

```
$('#aud1').get(0).play()
```

Veja a documentação do `get()`:

> https://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 1):

O método **play** pertence à tag html de áudio. Tem que aceder directamente ao elemento html e invocar o método play.

Para aceder ao elemento html usando jQuery:

```
$('#aud1')[0].play()
```